# angularjs - add `$index` into `ng-model`

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code:

```
<ul class="unstyled">
    <li class="card" ng-repeat="user in users">
        <form ng-submit="edit()">
            <input type="text" ng-model="editname"  size="30"placeholder="add name here">
            <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="edit">
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

which `card` class will be duplicate based on `users` array. I want to have unique `ng-model` so that when I edit one of them, it will not affect others. I believe I can use `$index`. How can I make

```
ng-model="editname"
```

into

```
ng-model="editname + $index"
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How about `user.name`?

Answer (score 1):

Try to naming model with ng-repeat instance

Like this

```
 ng-model="user.editname"
```

You can check duplicate on `$scope.users` list by editname property

Comment: It works! But I have another problem. How can I now pass this edited `ng-model` to update in the array?

Comment: pass user to edit like this `ng-submit="edit(user)"`

Comment: but already this will be updated with change in model as this model belong to the list

Comment: You are right. It just work magically without another additional code.

Answer (score 1):

If you really care about the index, you can set the index on the user instance. Then use 'user.index' as the model name. If not, you can use the answer by Anik.